# Tracking file download progress with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, download, progress-bar

I have a simple download page. When the user click on "download" button, it want to show the progress (in the progress bar) of the download. Also I want to track the file is download or not. Can I able to do this with php and Jquery. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the download progress is not possible via jQuery or anything else.

See the accepted answer for this post [Can I use jQuery UI Progress Bar to indicate the progress of downloading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595317/can-i-use-jquery-ui-progress-bar-to-indicate-the-progress-of-downloading-a-file) for the reasons why.