# Progress Bar for downloading files using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have created a page to download multiple files as a single zip file using JSZip plugin. While downloading the files the browser seems to be hanged so I want to show a progress bar that shows the progress of downloading the files. I am new to JavaScript and jQuery so I am unable to use the code found on various sites. Here is one of the [links](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_progressbar.htm) that I would prefer to use in my code.

I would like to show the progress on the basis of number of files. I am having one for each loop which iterates on each file. Please help me to use the code in the above link. Many thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have written:

```
document.getElementById("downloadZip").addEventListener("click", function ()
        {
            sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
            var docList = JSON.parse('{!docList}');
            var checkedRecords = [];
            for(var key in docList)
            {
                if(docList.hasOwnProperty(key))
                {
                    var isSelected = document.getElementById(docList[key].docRecordId).firstChild.checked;
                    if(isSelected)
                    {
                        checkedRecords.push(docList[key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(checkedRecords);
            if(checkedRecords.length > 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = '';
                var fileIdList = [];
                for(var key in checkedRecords)
                {
                    if(checkedRecords.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    {
                        var currentFile = checkedRecords[key];
                        var fileIdMap = checkedRecords[key].docFileMap;
                        var fileId;
                        for(var j in fileIdMap)
                        {
                            fileId = fileIdMap[j];
                        }
                        fileIdList.push(fileId);
                    }
                }
                var zip = new JSZip();
                var content = null;

                for(var key in fileIdList)
                {
                    if(fileIdList.hasOwnProperty(key))
                    {
                        var query = "Select Id,Title,Description,ContentUrl,ContentDocumentId,VersionData,PathOnClient,FileType From ContentVersion WHERE Id = '" + fileIdList[key] + "'";
                        try
                        {
                            var result = sforce.connection.query(query);
                            var records = result.getArray("records");
                            var filename = records[0].PathOnClient;
                            var packCount = 1;
                            if(filename === '')
                            {
                                filename = 'ContentPack_'+packCount;
                                packCount++;
                            }
                            zip.file(filename, records[0].VersionData,{base64: true});
                        }
                        catch(err)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = 'Content Not Found - ' + err.message;
                            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.color = 'red';
                        }
                    }
                }
                content = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
                saveAs(content, "myZip.zip");
                var sentTo = document.getElementById("ChooseSentTo").value;
                updateDocumentation(checkedRecords,sentTo);
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = 'Please select a record';
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.color = 'red';
            }
        });
```

Comment: show us what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sforce` is from the Salesforce AJAX Toolkit then you will need to use the [async methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples_asynch.htm).

I strongly suspect the synchronous methods to do sync ajax requests : the browser UI will freeze until *every* requests complete and the zip result is ready. Even if you use a progress bar, the updates won't show if the UI is frozen.

With async requests, the browser won't freeze anymore : it will be able to display the progress bar updates.

In the code below, `fetchDataFromSForces` transforms a `sforce` call to a jQuery Deferred (you want jQuery UI so I assumed that you have jQuery on your page). Manually merging async callback can lead to an ugly code and Deferred does that nicely. I didn't copy/paste the block that generate `fileIdList` to keep this answer readable, don't forget to put it back.

Without a Salesforce server I can't test this code so there may be some typos, small bugs, etc.

```
/**
 * Fetch data from the server asynchronously and add files in the zip.
 * @param {String} id the id of the ContentVersion to fetch.
 * @param {JSZip} zip the zip file to fill in.
 * @param {SForce} sforce the Sales Force object.
 * @return {jQuery.Deferred} the deferred containing the result.
 */
function fetchDataFromSForces(id, zip, sforce) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var query = "Select Id,Title,Description,ContentUrl,ContentDocumentId,VersionData,PathOnClient,FileType From ContentVersion WHERE Id = '" + id + "'";
    sforce.connection.query(query, {
        onSuccess : function (result) {
            var currentProgress = $(".your-progressbar").progressbar("option", "value") || 0;
            currentProgress++;

            // put the result in the zip
            var records = result.getArray("records");
            var filename = records[0].PathOnClient;
            if(filename === '') {
                filename = 'ContentPack_'+currentProgress;
            }
            zip.file(filename, records[0].VersionData,{base64: true});

            // update the progress bar
            $(".your-progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", currentProgress);

            deferred.resolve(zip);
        },
        onFailure : function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}

// Create your progress bar first.
$(".your-progressbar").progressbar();

document.getElementById("downloadZip").addEventListener("click", function () {

    // ...
    // Here, the previous code here to init sforce and get fileIdList
    // ...

    var zip = new JSZip();
    var deferreds = [];

    for(var key in fileIdList) {
        if(fileIdList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            deferreds.push(fetchDataFromSForces(fileIdList[key], zip, sforce));
        }
    }
    // re-init the progress bar
    $(".your-progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", 0);
    $(".your-progressbar").progressbar("option", "max", fileIdList.length);
    // join all deferreds into one
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
        var content = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
        saveAs(content, "myZip.zip");
        var sentTo = document.getElementById("ChooseSentTo").value;
        updateDocumentation(checkedRecords,sentTo);
    }).fail(function (err) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = err.message;
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.color = 'red';
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for replying. Yes it makes sense to use asynchronous syntax of ajax calls. I have also tried your method of using Progress bar on my page. But I am unable to use it. Progressbar methods are undefined. Though the JS Libraries are there. 
Please help me to understand this code so that I can use this code in my for loop and increase the progress accordingly.

Comment: $(function() {
var progressbar = $( "#progressbar-5" );progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );$( "#progressbar-5" ).progressbar({value: false,
change: function() {progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" ); },
complete: function() { progressLabel.text( "Loading Completed!" );}});
function progress() {var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0; progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + 1 );if ( val < 99 ) {setTimeout( progress, 100 );}}setTimeout( progress, 3000 );});

Comment: The code in your last comment works : http://jsfiddle.net/um1mkzog/ I just added jQuery (js) and jQuery UI (js, css). Could you create a jsfiddle of your code that doesn't work if you still have the issue ?

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot in understanding the issue I was facing and I could figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's up to the browser UI, not in the HTML/DOM interface, see the comment [Can I use jQuery UI Progress Bar to indicate the progress of downloading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595317/can-i-use-jquery-ui-progress-bar-to-indicate-the-progress-of-downloading-a-file?rq=1)

Comment: I am open to use jQuery-UI plugins as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: For Chrome, the only way for now to access download is via an extension https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Comment: I think you didn't get what I am asking. I want to use the code of progress bar to use in a for loop and increase the progress on the basis of for loop(the number of times that loop executes). I have provided the link of progress bar above in my question.