# Add progress indicator on download button

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

How to add progress indicator on download button(and shows till download report finishes)
Had tried progress tag of html 5 but it is not in sync with download status.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Is this really about Java? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: @Burkhard actually its java web project.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question and I don't think it can be answered as it stands. Maybe add a mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595317/can-i-use-jquery-ui-progress-bar-to-indicate-the-progress-of-downloading-a-file